# Strange memory leaks with ionic while initializing push notifications cause freezing

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, memory-leaks, ionic-framework

I'm facing some very strange memory issues since a couple of days.

The problem is, that ocassionally the apps is stuck and starts to increase the memory usage very fast until it crashes. While the memory is increasing, the app is freezing completly.

After some debugging I identified that this code is causing the error:

```
angular.module('app.shared').factory('PushNotificationService',         PushNotificationService);

PushNotificationService.$inject = [
    '$q',
    'MessagingService'
];

function PushNotificationService($q, MessagingService) {
var me = this;

initialize();

return {
    getStartupMessage: getStartupMessage,
    fetchToken: fetchToken
};

/**
 * Constructor
 * @return {[type]} [description]
 */
function initialize() {
    me.pusher = null;
    me.deviceToken = null;
    me.startupMessage = null;
}

/**
 * Fetches the push token through device interface
 *
 * @return {$q} Promises
 */
function fetchToken() {
    if (me.pusher != null) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log('PushService.fetchToken(): Got pusher', me.pusher);

            // when pusher was already initialized, we do not need to fetch it again
            console.log('PushService.fetchToken(): Token was already retrieved', me.deviceToken);
            resolve(me.deviceToken);
        });
    }

    console.log('PushService.fetchToken(): Needs to fetch token bc not retrieved yet');

    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            console.log('PushService.fetchToken(): Device is ready', typeof resolve, typeof reject);

            resolve(true);
        }, false);
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('PushService.fetchToken(): No pusher retrieved yet, do it now');

        return __initialize();
    }).then(function(push) {
        console.log('PushService.fetchToken(): Got pusher and start attaching events to it', push);

        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            push.on('error', function(error) {
                console.log('PushNotificationService.fetchToken(): Error while retrieving token', error.message, error);

                reject(error);
            });

            push.on('registration', function(data) {
                console.log('PushNotificationService.fetchToken(): Successfully retrieved token', data);

                me.deviceToken = data.registrationId;

                resolve(data.registrationId);
            });

            console.log('PushNotificationService.fetchToken(): Eventhandlers of pusher', push._handlers);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Initializes the push notifications and tries to fetch the Push token
 * @return {Cordova.Pusher} [description]
 */
function __initialize() {
    me.pusher = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
            senderID: "288503736094"
        },
        ios: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
            clearBadge: true
        },
        windows: {}
    });

    me.pusher.on('notification', __incomingNotification);

    return me.pusher;
}

// additional code which is not relevant here...
// .....
// .....
}
```

It happens only on iOS and is completly random, there is no way of finding a system in the crashes.

Debugging log looks like that:

```
PushService.fetchToken(): Needs to fetch token bc not retrieved yet 

PushService.fetchToken(): Device is ready function function 

PushService.fetchToken(): No pusher retrieved yet, do it now 

PushService.fetchToken(): Got pusher and start attaching events to it {"_handlers":{"registration":[],"notification":[null],"error":[]},"options":{"android":{"senderID":"288503736094"},"ios":{"alert":true,"badge":true,"sound":true,"clearBadge":true},"windows":{}}} 

PushNotificationService.fetchToken(): Eventhandlers of pusher {"registration":[null],"notification":[null],"error":[null]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue in the cordova-ios which caused massive memory leaks in random locations.

Upgrading to latest version fixed it!